# How pass reference in QThread

Tags: c++, qt, reference, qthread

How can i pass a reference from QThread, i tried to do this by the same method as std::thread but was unsuccessful.

Example code using std::thread

```
void test(int value, int &value2)
{
    value2 = value1 + 1;
    return;
}

int main()
{
   int value1 = 100;
   int value2 = NULL;

   std::thread thread(Testex, value1, std::ref(value2));
   thread.detach();

   std::cout << value2;
}
```

code that I tried to use, but I get the following error while compiling: 
"no matching function for call to 'invoke(std::remove_reference::type, int, int*)'"

```
void test(int value, int &value2)
{
    value2 = value1 + 1;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int value1 = 100;
    int value2 = NULL;

    QThread* qthread = QThread::create(test, value1, &value2);
    qthread ->start();

    qDebug() << value2;

    return 0;
}
```

Part of qthread.h that contains the error:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
QThread *QThread::create(Function &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    using DecayedFunction = typename std::decay<Function>::type;
    auto threadFunction =
        [f = static_cast<DecayedFunction>(std::forward<Function>(f))](auto &&... largs) mutable -> void
        {
            (void)std::invoke(std::move(f), std::forward<decltype(largs)>(largs)...);
        };

    return createThreadImpl(std::async(std::launch::deferred,
                                       std::move(threadFunction),
                                       std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: I added the error in the post, I can't compile the second code.

Comment: `&value2` creates an `int*` pointer, which is not what `test()` is expecting.  Besides, even if you could get the code to compile, it still has **undefined behavior** in it.  `value2` can go out of scope, leaving the thread with a dangling reference, before the thread has a chance to access it. And the code that starts the thread is using `value2` before the thread may have had a chance to update its value. This code needs to wait for the thread to finish running before it outputs the value of `value2`, and it needs to keep `value2` in scope until the thread exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is a little late but might help:

I found the solution like this:

You may use `std::bind(function, arg1, arg2)` and `std::ref` or `std::reference_wrapper<type>(var)` to pass the reference argument.

The final code is like the following:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

void test(int value1, int &value2)
{
    value2 = value1 + 1;
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //MainWindow w;
    //w.show();

    int value1 = 100;
    int value2 = 0;
    qDebug()<<"Value 1" << value1;
    QThread* qthread = QThread::create(std::bind(test,value1, std::ref(value2)));
    //This also works
    // QThread* qthread = QThread::create(std::bind(test,value1, std::reference_wrapper<int>(value2)));
    qthread ->start();
    // waiting for QThread to finish its task otherwise we would read the old value of value which is 0 instead of 101
    qthread->wait(); 
    // read only after the thread finishes
    qDebug()<<"Value 2" << value2;

    return 0;
}
```

Do not forget to wait for the `QThread` to finish otherwise you will read the former value and not the new value computed by the `QThread`

This code would give a result like this:

```sh
Value 1 100
Value 2 101
```

**Remark:** I had to use the syntax `QThread *QThread::create(Function &&f)` (not `QThread::create(Function &&f, Args &&... args)` like you) because I do not have C++17 but the idea is similar to pass a reference.